# Img stretched when other elements are styled exactly the same?

Tags: html, css

I'm somewhat familiar with html and css but i cant seem to find out why the image for Moriel Weiner is stretched. I'm inspecting the img element and its styled just like the others so I'm a bit confused. Sorry if my wording is off. Also its not my website I'm just in charge of uploading stuff to the website through sFTP Client if that helps.

Here is the page

http://www.kristolgroup.com/our_team.cfm

Comment: Moriel's image is not loading. Have you removed it?

Comment: right now the image not load at all.. i guess the image size is not the same ratio as the image style

Comment: You need to upload the image again so we can help.

Comment: thank you for bringing it to my attention. I just reuploaded it. The page should be back to it's original state. I was trying to troubleshoot the problem by uploading another img and changing the cfm txt file.

Comment: @yngtunafish still missing the image: http://www.kristolgroup.com/images/Headshot_Mo_Weiner_2020.jpg

Comment: my apologies. I uploaded the image into the wrong subfolder. Now when I refreshed the page the image is there but still stretched of course. I don't know too much about web dev but the subfolders to the site appears to be a mess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One solution is setting the property `object-fit` to `cover` to fit the width and height without stretching.

```css
img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: You're very welcome. 
If this provided the best solution to your problem you can accept this answer as the solution. Learn more in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

That image is 200x200, you will need to resize it to 127x196 like all other images.